# Is anybody able to diagnose anything from these Live Data Reports ? Car has loss of power and black smoke

Tags: ford, diesel, power, ranger, smoke

Photo's attached

Ford Ranger 2015 XLT 3.2L 4x4 Diesel Automatic

Currentl experiencing power loss and hesitation as well as black smoke out the exhaust[image]

Comment: can you get a reading of the back pressure in your exhaust manifold or hear if the sound from your exhaust pipe sounds restricted,is this some thing that happened gradualy.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, I took it to a mechanic who said he hears a hissing towards my EGR valve area, it all happened, right after i dismantled my EGR valve and reattatched it.

Comment: this is important information to edit into your question,do you have any other information you might want to edit into your question.

Comment: add full details of everything you did to the egr and whether the problem was evident before. Egr info notwithstanding it sounds to me like you have a boost leak- Split intercooler or hoses  etc