# Two Exact Cars, Two Live Data Graphs - What the hell does this mean?

Tags: ford, fuel-system, leak

Ford Ranger XLT 3.2L 4x4 2015 Diesel Automatic

Live data from both vehicles,

One on The left side is driving completely normal, the one on the right, has a loss of power, hesitation and black smoke coming out the back.

As you can see, the fuel level input is significantly higher on the poor performing car (Right side)

There was speculation to a boost leak due to a gasket being missing around the EGR valve area, Would this cause this ?

Any thoughts or ideas ?[image]

Comment: Easy enough, fix the leak, then see if it changes the fuel stats.

Comment: It was speculation to a leak, not a confirmed one. 

Would these figures suggest there would be a leak ?

Comment: Would possible, leaky fuel injectors give these readings?

Comment: anything is possible but I doubt it is the cause.

Comment: Would you think this leans more towards a boost leak then leaky injectors? MAFS sensor overcompensating for lack of air by injecting more fuel ?

Comment: See this question: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/74665/10976 and consider keeping one with all the info.

Comment: BUMP

Need answers